sidebar text overflows out of its limit
im trying to make a sidebar where the texts/links should be in the center of the side bar but the text keeps on overflowing out of it becuase the words become longer and i dont know how to fix it, ive tried using padding and margin but it wont work . i am hoping someone can help find out what im doing wrong because i cant find the answer or where the problem is even


*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar{
    background-color: rgb(189, 186, 186);
    width: 10vw;
    font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.sidebar nav{
    padding: 40px;
    
}

.sidebar nav li{
   
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 33px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
 
}

.main{
   
    width: 90vw;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
}

.infoContainer{
   
    height: 58vh;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 140px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.devInfo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
    margin: 10px;
}

.hello{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.name{
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}
.about{
 font-size: 20px;
}

.moreAbout{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

.buttons {
    margin-top: 34px;
}
.buttons button{
    padding: 9px 14px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    color: white;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin: 0 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.devPic img{
    height: 58vh;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/intro.html">My Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="infoContainer">
      <div class="devInfo">
        <div class="hello">Hi I am</div>
        <div class="name">Awais Rafique</div>
        <div class="about">Developer, Programmer, Software Engineer</div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



i tried using padding and margin to shift the content into the middle more but its not responding like i hope it would

Overflow only works with constrained width, where your li is lacking.

Don’t set fixed widths for your sidebar or your main container, just let them work out their widths automatically.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: rgb(189, 186, 186);
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 2em;
}

.sidebar nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2em;
}

.sidebar nav a {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.infoContainer {
  height: 58vh;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: 140px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.devInfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
  margin: 10px;
}

.hello {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
}

.about {
  font-size: 20px;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <a href="/intro.html">My Intro</a>
      <a href="/services.html">Services</a>
      <a href="/contact.html">Contact Me</a>
      <a href="/blog.html">Blog</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="infoContainer">
      <div class="devInfo">
        <div class="hello">Hi I am</div>
        <div class="name">Awais Rafique</div>
        <div class="about">Developer, Programmer, Software Engineer</div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



